# nested dynamic JSON data to Extjs Model

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I want to transform this json to Extjs Model:

```
{
  "TableHour": {
    "0": {
      "Rx": 0,
      "Tx": 0
    },
    "1": {
      "Rx": 2,
      "Tx": 0
    },
    "2": {
      "Rx": 0,
      "Tx": 0
    },
    "3": {
      "Rx": 6,
      "Tx": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried :

```
Ext.define("TableHour", {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        hasMany:  { model:'TableMode' }
    });

    Ext.define("TableMode", {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
        'Rx','Tx'
        ],          
        belongsTo: 'TableHour',
    });     

    var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore',{
        autoLoad: true,
        model:'TableHour',
        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            url:'HoursReports.json',
            reader:{
                type: 'json',
            }
        }

    });   
    console.log(store1.getAt(0));
```

But the last line, print "undefined". It's sure that model definition is wrong. 
The numbers "0" "1" "2" "3"  aren't declared in my model beacause they're dynamically generated... how can i do?

Comment: How are the numbers generated? Is it done in the JS or in the backend somewhere?

Comment: it's done with .net framework, i generate an object with a sortedList<int,TableMode> object, and JsonNet print the json object format. Does it is a right choice for pass data to Extjs for generate charts?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON data appears to contain an object with numeric properties as a collection. In order to work with ExtJS this should be an array instead:

```
{
  "TableHour": [
    {
      "Rx": 0,
      "Tx": 0
    },{
      "Rx": 2,
      "Tx": 0
    },{
      "Rx": 0,
      "Tx": 0
    },{
      "Rx": 6,
      "Tx": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, if you want to work with a store, then `TableHour` should be the data root and there should be only one model "TableMode":

```
Ext.define("TableMode", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'Rx', 'Tx'
    ]
});

var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore',{
    autoLoad: true,
    model: 'TableMode',
    proxy: {
        type:'ajax',
        url: 'HoursReports.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'TableHour'
        }
    }
});
```

Check out [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hd6) for a working example.

Comment: Thanks for response, but if i want to view also "0" "1" "2"..(same of my initial example) how can i do?

Comment: @matt is correct, this is just a mistake in data modelling. The model should not have N-number of dynamic properties with integers as property names. This better modelled as an array of objects, each with their own properties `[{id: 0, Rx: 0, Tx: 0}, {id: 1, Rx: 2, Tx: 0}, {id: 2, Rx: 0, Tx: 0}, {id: 3, Rx: 6, Tx: 0}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loading the store automatically using its load () method, you could load the data with Ext.Ajax.request () and transform the data in the success callback such that it has the required format. Then you can feed it into your store.

The data has to look something like this :

```
{
  "TableHour": [
    {
      "Id": 0,
      "Rx": 0,
      "Tx": 0
    },{
      "Id": 1,
      "Rx": 2,
      "Tx": 0
    },{
```

Comment: Now i'm generating this in backend. How to rapresent it in Extjs store? I'm confusing (specially with hasOne associations)

Comment: I don't have experience with associations. I had problem getting them to work, and finally I didn't need them.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified my backend generated Json. Now my json is:

```
{
  "Date": null,
  "TableHourDto": [
    {
      "Hour": "0",
      "Rx": 3,
      "Tx": 5
    },
    {
      "Hour": "1",
      "Rx": 2,
      "Tx": 0
    },
    {
      "Hour": "2",
      "Rx": 0,
      "Tx": 0
    },
    {
      "Hour": "3",
      "Rx": 5,
      "Tx": 0
    }
}
```

My Extjs model is:

```
Ext.define("TableHour", {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',       
                fields: [
                'Hour','Rx','Tx'
                ],
            });
```

And my store:

```
var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore',{
                autoLoad:true,
                proxy:{
                    type:'ajax',
                    url:'HoursReports.json',                    
                    reader:{
                        type: 'json',
                        model:'TableHour',
                        root: 'TableHourDto',
                        listeners : {
                            exception: function( reader, response, error, eOpts ){
                                console.log('Got exception');
                            }
                        }
                    }                   
                },
                listeners:{
                    load:function( store, records, successful, eOpts ){
                        console.log(store.getAt(0).data);
                        // This print first: Object {Hour: "0", Rx: 3, Tx: 5}
                    }
                }
            });
```

Having this store, i will build relative Charts...
Thank all for reply